# settin up a text input value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I'm creating a scoring ballot to score submitted contest videos. I use the same HTML form for all videos to score. The only fields that are being dynamically updated with java script are: judge name and a contestant name. My problem is the value that I set up with java script is showing on the form itself but is not recorded in a csv file.

Here is my HTML:
           
               Select your name
               Judge#1
               Judge#2
               Judge#3
               Judge#4
               Judge#5
               Judge#6
           
Based on this option select they would get a set of videos they have not completed scoring on, and first scoring form with video embedded is displayed. Initially they are hidden on the page.

```
    <form id="ballot1" action="javascript: sendBallot()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%" id="table3">
     <tr> 
       <td><input type="hidden" name="Contestant" value="Contestant1"></td>
       <td width="78%"><input name="form_judge" id="form_judge" value=""></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><p><span style="font-size:1em;"><strong>1. Efficacy of Practice - 50%</strong></span></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label class="ballot">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a. Video explores relevant subject matter  </label>
    </td>
    <td>
       <select class="ballot" id="one_a_score" name="one_a_score" valign="bottom">
         <option value="0" selected>Select Score</option>
         <option value="2">Poor</option>
         <option value="4">Below average</option>
         <option value="6">Average</option>
         <option value="8">Good</option>
         <option value="10">Excellent</option>
       </select>
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   <div class="buttons">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" id="submit"/> 
     <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="resetBtn"/>
   </div>
```

My java script to set up the form values:

```
function showBallotForm(divName) {
    var divName = 'Contestant1';
    document.getElementById(divName).style.display='';
    var selectjudgeName = document.getElementById("judgeName");
    oFormObject = document.forms['ballot1'];
    oFormElement = oFormObject.elements['form_judge'];
    oFormElement.value = selectjudgeName.options[selectjudgeName.selectedIndex].value;
   }
```

var divName = 'Contestant1';  -  this will be deleted as soon as I figure out why judge name is set up and showing on the form with no problem, but when I enter all scores and hit "submit" button, entire form is recorded in csv file, except for one value (form_judge) that was set dynamically. By the way, I tried to use getElementById insted of oFormElement, the result is the same. I can see it on the form, but it records just word 'judge' in the csv file, not the actual name.
What am I missing? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite grasp what your javascript does because there are several errors in it:

```
function showBallotForm(divName) {
    var divName = 'Contestant1';
```

The divName parameter is never used since it is immediatly re-written?

```
document.getElementById(divName).style.display='';
```

No idea what you wanted here, you want to display the hidden input?

```
var selectjudgeName = document.getElementById("judgeName");
```

There is no element with "judgeName" id on your HTML, so this won't work, I will suppose you did not paste the full code then

```
oFormObject = document.forms['ballot1'];
oFormElement = oFormObject.elements['form_judge'];
```

Ok, but you could do this by simply using document.getElementByid("form_judge")

```
oFormElement.value = selectjudgeName.options[selectjudgeName.selectedIndex].value;
```

But here is your error. You cannot set a value on a select. I see the object is an input but this is weird since I can't even see where selectJudgeName came from! The data that is send on the form is the selectedIndex, not the value. So what you want is to find which option you want and point to it something like this:

```
oFormElement.selectedIndex = (the index of the option you want)
```

If you don't know the index, you will have to look for it on the oFormElementobject, just do a for loop searching which of the option have the value you want, and when you find it, set that as the selectedIndex and break out.

Also, what submits this is a javascript you named in the action, you sure that is sending the proper data?